# Getting recycle bin folder with CSIDL_BITBUCKET resulting in garbled strings

Tags: c++builder

My environment

```
C++ Builder XE4 on Windows 7 Pro (32bit)
```

I am trying to get Path for "Recycle Bin" using [CSIDL_XXX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx).

Unit2.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm2::B_checkRecycleBinClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    //LPTSTR getPath[255];
    wchar_t appdata[255];
    SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, appdata, CSIDL_APPDATA, false);
    OutputDebugString(appdata);

    wchar_t recycle[255];
    SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, recycle, CSIDL_BITBUCKET, false);
    OutputDebugString(recycle);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With the above code,

- I can get APPDATA path
- recycle path is garbled

Q. What is the mistake you can recognize?

Comment: Try checking return codes.

Comment: I added try, catch showing Exception &exc. But it did not show error (normal operation).

Comment: SHGetSpecialFolderPath returns a value. Check it.

Comment: I also tried executing the .exe with Administrative privilege resulting in the same way.

Comment: SHGetSpecialFolderPath () did return false. But I don't know the reason yet.

Comment: It seems that the above is related to http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/eb60eae5f2e5ac99.htm (Mark Henr #8/ 9)

Comment: In other words: the recycle bin is not a real path to a single directory, it is a shell folder. You can get a `PItemIDList` for it (using `SHGetFolderLocation`), but not a proper path (using `SHGetSpecialFolderPath`).

Comment: You're right. I gave up getting the path for the recycle bin. I also found the way to use directly "C:\\$Recycle.Bin". But this may not be a good way for  the future OS.